# How to implement this flexible layout without flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement flexible layout looks like on the images I've attached.

It is modal window with fixed height. Header height cannot be fixed and can changes automatically during the window resize process e.g. In thi case content area height should be recalculated so modal window should save the same height.

I cannot use flexbox due to IE9 supporting reason.
Could someone please tell me, how can I implement such layout?

[image: state 1]
[image: state 2]

I tried to solve this problem using javascript. this is an example what I did(pseudo-code):

`window.resize(() = { if (checkHeaderHeight() > 75px) recalculateContentheight();  })`

Also I tried to use tables but I could not get any acceptable solution to attach my code here.

For example, my modal window have to have all available viewport space. There is a solution for the header with fixed height: `height: 75px` for the header and `height: calc(100vh - 75px); overflow-y: auto;` for the content area.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: If you don't want header to have height than don't assign height to it. As long as there is text it will expand and shrink based on browser width. Hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Also show us what you have done besides thinking about flexbox.

Comment: Actually I don't have any solution to attach my code. I've added two approaches that I consider.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I try to achieve exactly I described. I need container with fixed height that has two children - header and content. They should occupy all available vertical space in the parent container. Content area has 'overflow-y: auto' property, can have vertical scrollbar and contains much content. Header area should have flexible height. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will attempt to answer :) You can set the heights on window resize event

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/11ayLL01/

```
<div id='header'>
  header
  <p>
    another line
  </p>
</div>
<div id='container'>
  container
</div>
<script>
function resize(){
  var windwow_height = window.innerHeight;
  var header_height = document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
  var container_height = windwow_height - header_height;

  document.getElementById('container').style.height = container_height + 'px';
  document.getElementById('container').style.maxHeight = container_height + 'px';
}
window.onresize = resize; 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resize);

<script>
<style>
#container {
  background: aliceblue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, it is :) It's good solution for me(I don't have any other solutions). But maybe do you know how to achieve this result without js?

Comment: Ohh without JS, no. You can't do that and have a dynamic header I don't think. Why can't you use JS?

Comment: I can, but I see there some issues - try to add longer text line and then resize window in your example - you will see how scrollbar appeared sometimes when recalculation occurs

Comment: well, there has to be a scrollbar or you wouldn't be able to see the content...

Comment: I mean that scrollbar appears and dissappears(during 0.5s) even there is no content in the content area, looks like a bug. But, it doesn't matter actually. Anyway - thanks!